# using a case when to include substr and instr

Tags: substr

please can you help:
this is my string (the string length differs):

WWWWWWWWW/XXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYRTDZZZZK/**123**/CQW/321/AAAAAAAAAA

What i want is to capture 123 (or whatever number is between the / /)
I tried this:
substr(MSG_TEXT,instr(MSG_TEXT, '/K')+2,INSTR(MSG_TEXT,'/CQW')-instr(msg_text,'/K')-2)

which does works, if there is no more K/ before it, somtimes there is.

so it didn't like this:
WWWWWK/WWWW/XXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYY**RTD**ZZZZK/123/CQW/321/AAAAAAAAAA

I want it to start looking from RTD onwards, as it will be the first /K it finds

so I've tried this (trying to start about 50 characters in before RTD but after the first K/):
case when substr(msg_text,50,200) like '%RTD%' then substr(substr(MSG_TEXT,instr(MSG_TEXT, '/K')+2,INSTR(MSG_TEXT,'/CQW')-instr(msg_text,'/K')-2),50,200) end

but it returned null!

I know i'm on the right track, appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a bit more context? Like what language you're using (SQL?), and what exactly do you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, Oracle SQL, and i want to retreive the number between / and / after it finds RTD

Comment: i have worked it out, i put the substr(instr in the table join itself rather than the select statement. now the string it brings me start where i want it.